# Is it possible to create a pdf from a dynamically created table in react with jsPDF?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jspdf

My application gives quotes to customers near a specific location.  I generate a table of quotes based on the search criteria.  I would like to create a pdf document to then send the customer their quote.  I've dabble with jsPDF a little bit, but it doesn't seem like there is a way to create the pdf when the html is dynamically created.  I figured that if I wrapped the table in a div that I could just get the element by id, but I keep getting an error that 'name' is undefined.  Any suggestions would be awesome! Thanks.

Here is an example of how I generate my table within react.

```
var renderlist = [];

for(var i = 0; i < storelist.length; i++){

  renderlist.push(
   <tr>
    <td>{somestoreinfo}</td>
   </tr>
  )
}

renderTable(){
 <div id="tabletorender">
  <tbody>
    {renderlist}
  </tbody>
 </div>

}
```

This is what I am returning within react

```
render(){
 return(
  <div id="pdf">
    {this.renderTable.bind(this)}
  </div>
<button onClick={this.exportPDF.bind(this)}> Export PDF <button>
 );
}
```

Here is where I create the pdf

```
    exportPDF(){
        var doc = new jsPDF();
        var source = document.getElementById('pdf').innerHTML
        doc.fromHTML(source, 15, 15);
        doc.save('a4.pdf');
    }
```

This isn't the full code, because the actual code is a few thousand lines long, but this is just an example.

**EDIT**: "somestoreinfo" includes the quote and the store location etc...

Comment: Could you also share the set of code where you use jsPDF?

Comment: @GauthamK sorry, just updated my answer.

Comment: Can you used **var source = document.getElementById('pdf');** and check?

Comment: I get the same issue.  Says cannot read property 'name' of undefined.